# crypto library not found in ethereumjs-wallet

Tags: wallets

I am importing ethereumjs-wallet in angular4,

```
import EthereumWallet from 'ethereumjs-wallet';
var wallet = EthereumWallet.generate();
const jsV3 = wallet.toV3(passwd);
the code inside the library shown as below
```

> ```
> var privKey = crypto.randomBytes(32)
> ```

throws out an error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is
>   not a function TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function
>   TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function at
>   Function.webpackJsonp.../../../../ethereumjs-wallet/index.js.Wallet.generate

The same problem applies to

```
  var mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic();
  var privateKey = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(mnemonic)._hdkey._privateKey
  const wallet = EthereumWallet.fromPrivateKey(privateKey)
```

> ```
> TradePageComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: crypto.createHmac is not a function
>     at Function.webpackJsonp.../../../../hdkey/lib/hdkey.js.HDKey.fromMasterSeed
> ```
>
> (hdkey.js:162)
>           at Function.webpackJsonp.../../../../ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey.js.EthereumHDKey.fromMasterSeed
>   (hdkey.js:17)

how to solve the crypto library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crypto npm is deprecated and does not contain any code as such.
A dirty has is to replace

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
```

with

```
var crypto = require('crypto-browserify');
```